# Getting "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" with pattern.search

Tags: python, typeerror, python-re

I was working on a python program made to write out the IP addresses from an error log file. I got it coded but whenever I try it on my error log I get a

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I wrote the code under this in case anyone wants to see what I did specifically. If anyone knows my mistake that would be great.

```
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop/Test error file.txt') as fh:
   file = fh.readlines()

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')

list=[]

for line in file:
    lst.append(pattern.search(line)[0])

print(list)
```

Comment: Check the result of `pattern.search(line)` before trying to use it.  In this case, it's returning `None`, which is causing your error.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the error message _as part of the question itself_, not as a link to somewhere else (because in this case, the link leads to an "Access Denied" page).

Comment: Do not use a valid keyword list. Use other declaration variables like _list.

Answer (score 1):

[`pattern.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) returns `None` if no match is found. To account for this try

```
for line in file:
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match is not None:
        lst.append(match[0])
    else:
        lst.append(None)
```

Here I appended a `None` value if there was no match. You can change the logic to do what you need if there is no match.